# Interchange of supremum and integral

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f : X \to Y$, $X \subset R^n$, $Y$ Banach space, $g : X \times Y \to R \cup \{ \infty \}$, $L^n$ the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Are there some results under which the following interchange of supremum and integration
$$
\sup_{f:X \to Y} \int_X g(x, f(x)) \mathrm{d}L^n(x) = \int_X \sup_{q \in Y} g(x, q) dL^n(x)
$$
is valid?

Comment: My first instinct would be to look for a sequence $f_n$ that approximates the sup on both sides, and then use the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Your idea sounds reasonable, I will try and see if it works out.

Comment: On the right hand side you have a measurability problem. Apart from this, if (almost) all suprema $\sup\limits_{q\in Y}g(x,q)$ are attained then every function $f$ which chooses a maximal point (i.e., $f(x)$ satisfies $g(x,f(x))=\sup\limits_{q\in Y}g(x,q)$) gives equality.

Comment: One the right-hand side I would guess you should take the $esssup$ or else you can have a pathological version

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Could you please kindly expand on your comment, or point to a reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Theorem 2.1 and Remark 2.2 of https://cermics.enpc.fr/cermics-rapports-recherche/2006/CERMICS-2006/CERMICS-2006-321.pdf. Also see Theorem 14.60 of Rockafella and Wets' "Variational Analysis".